Can't make a transition animation between recycler view item and fragment details. Jetpack Navigation
I'm trying to create a transition animation between the ImageView of a RecyclerView item and the ImageView in a details fragment. I tried it with another view from the first fragment, outside of the RecyclerView, and the second fragment, and it's working fine. but if I try to make it from recycler view item, it doesn't work
Here is method of binding data from ViewHolder
fun bind(property: Property) {
    with(binding) {
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(ivProperty, property.propertyId)
        setPropertyImage(property)
        setBrandingLogoData(property.branding?.first())

        tvPropertyAddress.text = property.getName()
        tvPropertyPrice.text = property.listPrice?.toString()

        tvPropertyBeds.showText(property.description?.beds?.toString())
        tvProperyBaths.showText(property.description?.baths?.toString())
        tvPropertySqft.showText(property.description?.sqft?.toString())

        root.onClick { onItemClick(property, ivProperty) }
    }
}

onItemClick method from fragment with RecyclerView
fun openPropertyDetails(property: Property, view: ImageView) {
    val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
        view to view.transitionName
    )
    SearchFragmentDirections.openPropertyDetails(property, view.transitionName).navigate(extras)
}

Fragment Details code
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedElementEnterTransition =
        TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode)
}

override fun initViews() {
    with(binding) {
        postponeEnterTransition()
        ivProperty.transitionName = args.transitionName
        glideImage(args.property.primaryPhoto.url, ivProperty)
        setPropertyDescriptionFilters(args.property.description)
        setBrandingInfo(args.property.branding?.first())
        tvPropertyAddress.text = args.property.getName()
        tvPropertyPrice.text =
            getString(R.string.view_sale_property_description_price, args.property.listPrice)
        if (args.property.lastUpdateDate != null) {
            tvSalePropertyTime.text = getString(
                R.string.screen_sale_property_details_property_description_last_update_title,
                args.property.lastUpdateDate.toUiTime(
                    SERVER_YEAR_MONTH_DAY_TIME_PATTERN,
                    UI_DATE_PATTERN_WITH_TIME_AND_SPACE
                )
            )
            tvSalePropertyTime.show()
        }
    }
}

glideImage Method
fun Fragment.glideImage(url: String?, view: ImageView) = Glide.with(view)
.load(url)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
.skipMemoryCache(false)
.apply(
    RequestOptions().dontTransform() // this line
)
.addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
    override fun onLoadFailed(
        p0: GlideException?,
        p1: Any?,
        p2: Target<Drawable>?,
        p3: Boolean
    ): Boolean {
        Timber.i("startPostponedEnterTransition error")
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
        return false
    }

    override fun onResourceReady(
        p0: Drawable?,
        p1: Any?,
        p2: Target<Drawable>?,
        p3: DataSource?,
        p4: Boolean
    ): Boolean {
        Timber.i("startPostponedEnterTransition success")
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
        return false
    }
})
.into(view)

